# Allowing a domain name instead of an IP in Windows Firewall

Tags: windows-firewall, windows-server-2016

A client of mine retrieves records from a remote MSSQL instance using Excel about once a week, for which he is whitelisted on the Windows Server that instance is running on. Every once in a while his ISP however assigns him a new IP and I have to manually add it to the firewall in order to allow him back in.

Ideally I'd like him to start running DuckDNS or any other dynamic DNS service so that I can just whitelist a domain instead of having to manually make changes. Is this possible under Windows in any way? Whitelisting an entire range of IP's would solve the problem, but open up the server to way more machines that I'm comfortable with.

Does Windows Firewall have this ability and if so how do I configure it?

Comment: As far as I know, Windows Firewall doesn't support allow traffic from a specific domain name. Here is a similar thread discussed before, you could check if it was helpful: [Windows Firewall rule based on domain name instead of IP](https://serverfault.com/questions/180515/windows-firewall-rule-based-on-domain-name-instead-of-ip)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall works by IP address and not by domain-name.

A possible solution would be to create a PowerShell script and have it run
on login.
The script would then resolve the DNS name and create the new rule.
It should also delete the last rule, because otherwise they will accumulate,
perhaps even daily.

You could find usable PowerShell snippets (with some changes)
in the article
[How to Block a Domain or Website on Windows Defender Firewall with PowerShell?](http://woshub.com/block-domains-websites-windows-firewall-powershell/)